# Check file exists and has the right naming standard in C#

Tags: c#

We have a process from third-party vendor to drop sales and invetory data everyday and could have any of the following scenarios

1. Drop the right file. (Naming standard: test.xls)
2. Drop the right file but not follow the right naming standard. (Other
   names could be test_mmddyyyy or testmmddyyyy)
3. No file dropped.

*I am trying to build my logic around these scenarios and stuck at how to build my logic when the file exists but does not have the right naming standard and check for this condition and change the name of the file to the appropriate naming standard.*

```
public void Main()
{
    try
    {
        string filefullpathname = @"C:\Temp\test.xls";

        if (File.Exists(filefullpathname) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File does not exist in the path");
        }

        // file exists but right naming standard not followed (Other names could be test_mmddyyyy or testmmddyyyy)
        // how to check for this condition and change the name of the file to the naming standard
        else
        {
            string dirname = @"C:\Temp\";
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(dirname);
            string filepartialname = "test";

            FileInfo[] fileindirectory = directory.GetFiles(filepartialname + "*");

            foreach (FileInfo filename in fileindirectory)
            {
                string fullname = filename.FullName;
                bool ind = Path.HasExtension(fullname);

                if (ind == false)
                {
                    File.Move(fullname, directory + filepartialname + ".xls");
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Move(fullname, directory + filepartialname + ".xls");
                }
            }
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    catch (Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give a concrete example please ? What is constant in the filename and are the 3 formats you mentionned the only possible formats ?

Comment: I would start by checking for the dates of the file in the folder,  So by decreasing dates and take first file. :             string filename = new DirectoryInfo( @"C:\Temp").GetFiles("*.xls").OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTime).FirstOrDefault().FullName;

Comment: The name of the file "test" is constant and will have only one file everyday and every once in a while when the automated job fails the name and extension gets changed to "test_mmddyyyy.zip", "testmmddyyyy.zip", "test_mmddyyyy.xls", "testmmddyyyy.xls".

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear as to if it is only the file name or a missing extension.  So I put in both.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            string dirname = @"C:\Temp\";
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(dirname);
            string filepartialname = "test";

            FileInfo[] fileindirectory = directory.GetFiles(filepartialname + "*");

            foreach (FileInfo filename in fileindirectory)
            {
                if (filename.Extension == "")
                {
                    //doesn't have an extension                            
                }
                else if (!Regex.IsMatch(filename.Name.Replace(filename.Extension, ""), @"^[A-Z|a-z]$"))
                {
                    //contains more then just test
                }
                else
                {
                    //file is good
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation of what your inputs could be, and how you want to move those inputs isn't super clear, but this should get you started:

```
var expectedFilename = Path.Combine(someOtherDirectory, "test.xls");

// Matches test* and *.xls
var relevantFiles = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(searchDirectory, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(f => Path.GetFileName(f).StartsWith("test") || Path.GetExtension(f).Equals(".xls"))

foreach (var file in relevantFiles)
{
    // If there's more than one file matching the pattern, last one in wins
    File.Move(file, expectedFilename);
}
```